# Heroku Redis - Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6372 - certificate verify failed

Tags: ruby, heroku, redis

When I make my first call to sidekiq on Heroku, the following error is thrown:

```
Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6372
```

Which of course is not the IP of my Heroku:Redis. That URL is defined in my ENV vars as:

```
rediss://:blahblah@ecmore-numbers-here.compute-1.amazonaws.com:port
```

Interestingly in a Heroku console I do this:

```
redis = Redis.new
```

which correctly returns:

```
=> #<Redis client v4.2.5 for redis://blah-blah-blah.compute-1.amazonaws.com:port/0>
```

But then when I do:

```
redis.set("hey", "you")
```

I get:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (self signed certificate in certificate chain))
```

I have the following in my `sidekiq.rb`

```
require 'sidekiq'

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  Sidekiq::Status.configure_client_middleware config, expiration: 30.minutes
  if Rails.env.production?
    url = URI.parse(ENV["REDIS_URL"])
    url.scheme = "rediss"
    url.port = Integer(url.port) + 1
    config.redis = {
      url: url.to_s,
      network_timeout: 5,
      ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE }
    }
  end
end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  Sidekiq::Status.configure_server_middleware config, expiration: 30.minutes
  Sidekiq::Status.configure_client_middleware config, expiration: 30.minutes
  if Rails.env.production?
    url = URI.parse(ENV["REDIS_URL"])
    url.scheme = "rediss"
    url.port = Integer(url.port) + 1
    config.redis = {
      url: url.to_s,
      network_timeout: 5,
      ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE }
    }
  end
end
```

Here is my `redis.rb`

```
require 'uri'
url = URI.parse(ENV["REDIS_URL"])
url.scheme = "rediss"
url.port = Integer(url.port) + 1
$redis = Redis.new(url: url, driver: :ruby, ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE })
```

`Procfile`

```
release: bin/rails db:migrate
web: bin/start-stunnel bin/rails server -p ${PORT:-5000} -e $RAILS_ENV
worker: bin/start-stunnel bundle exec sidekiq
```

and I'm running
redis - 4.2.5
sidekiq - 6.2.0
ruby - 2.6.5

Comment: have you tried updating the Redis to v5 or v6?

Comment: Can you please try `redis = Redis.new(ssl_params: {verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE})` and then `redis.set`

Comment: Any updates on this ToddT?

Answer (score 1):

So Its an ssl verify cert error. I got the same error and find a solution via github

I tried to send verify_mode into ssl_paramss of redis instance like below

```
redis = Redis.new(ssl_params: {verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE})
```

You can find out https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/issues/940

also there is another flag `ssl: true or false` you can use that too